# Single-Boot Linux Acer Chromebook 15 CB5 "YUNA"

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, chromebook, chromeos

Model:      Acer Chromebook 15 CB5-571-C09S “YUNA” 
CPU:        Intel Celeron 3205U 1.5 GHz Processor (Broadwell Dual-Core) 
RAM:        4GB DDR3L SDRAM
HDD:        32GB SSD

I would like to SINGLE boot Linux and use this exclusively as a Linux laptop. 
I do not need to dual-boot and anticipate no need to restore to ChromeOS.

Everything I’ve seen seems to date from 2015-16 and is either (A) Installing a Linux distro via Crouton or (B) dual-booting. ChrUbuntu is dead, as far as I can tell.

I’ve browsed AskUbuntu, and Reddit/r/GalliumOS, https://chrx.org/, https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility#cite_note-TextMode-14, https://wiki.galliumos.org/Installing, but questions remain.

- Where is the guide for simply wiping the SSD and setting up Chromebook(s) as single-boot Linux?
- Should one always use GalliumOS / Xubuntu flavors on Acer Chromebooks?
- If so, should I just set up a GalliumOS installer USB, flash the BIOS, nuke the old SSD / install onto the 32gb SSD in there?

Sorry if this is a duplicate; please correct/redirect me if I’ve assumed anything erroneously. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I run Gallium on my Chromebook (CB5-571). There is a screw you need to remove on the back of the machine to disable write protection. I previously used crouton to run Ubuntu through a Chrome OS tab but I wanted to do away with Chrome OS completely so I opted for Gallium as it's optimized for Chromebooks. I'm running upgraded firmware as well.

First check that your HW is supported.
https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility

They have detailed instructions on how to install here:
https://wiki.galliumos.org/Installing/Preparing